# requesting access from Twitter on Sharekit?

Tags: twitter, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit and it used to work perfectly without any pbm, since two days I still get this error message whenever I try to share something with Sharekit in my app

```
There was a problem requesting access from Twitter
```

Sharing with other services like Facebook or Email still working well.

Did you noticed a similar problem? any fixes?

For more info : when I try sharing somthing, It request all time my approval to the application, even I did that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed, [get the latest ShareKit version](https://www.github.com/sharekit/sharekit).

Comment: I tried to get user id using facebook account, but I get this warning and didn't work :[ User info not possible to download on iOS sharing. You can get service enabled user info from Accounts framework ] Any idea :( thanks.

Comment: As you read, SHKShareTypeUserInfo does not work on social.framework sharers yet, unfortunately. You have to pull it from Accounts framework on your own. Or you can force pre iOS Facebook sharing in configurator.

Comment: Sorry for any disturbance Vilèm Kurz, is there any "more simple" way or fork for Sharekit that I can use? without having to complete all the steps for each project I'm doing? I mean is there previous version working well, there were more simple to integrate, because I'm not so familiar with Git..

Comment: It is not that complicated, if you follow wiki install. You can get it running in 10-15 minutes actually. I am not aware of a fork, which is more up to date, and more straightforward to use then ours. The problem is, that earlier versions are not working (sometimes) as the services do change their api's quite often.